# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '\[\]' Receiver: Closure: () =\> Map\<String, dynami....)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am unable to solve this exception that appeared in my application: An exception occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]'
Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
Tried calling: Found: => Map<String, dynamic>)

```
GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var ourData = snapshot.data[index];

                  return Card(
                    elevation: 10.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      child:
                          Image.network(ourData.data['img'], fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              ),
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

I hope that the images stored in my Cloud Firestore will load on the page.

Comment: Is snapshot the Firestore snapshot? It so, try adding () to the data.
```var ourData = snapshot.data()```

Comment: I am using FirebaseFirestore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data structure is like. But, I think it's not a List but a Map<String, dynamic>.

So, if you want to get the data from FireStore, try this.

```
// Change ref to suit your conditions.
final snapshot = await ref.get();
final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

And then, convert this Map<String, dynamic> data to List.